# In proving the product rule, how do we know to add and subtract f(x+h)g(x) from the numerator in the derivative definition?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I watched two YouTube videos to try to get a proof that makes sense, but in both videos, the authors said something to the effect of "add and subtract f(x+h)g(x)" without a good explanation as to how to come up with that step (in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNhYfmC_UPU), for example, the author just says "this will make everything work out here".)

Comment: Do you mean you don't see how we could think to do that? Sometimes it's just a lucky guess in a proof step that makes it work, and that's OK.

Comment: @JonathanHebert "Do you mean you don't see how we could think to do that?" Yes.

Comment: The inspiration come from the definition of the derivative of a function that is not written as a product of 2 differentiable functions.

Comment: You shouldn't worry that you did not see this step, rather you should now try and embrace this new tool in your toolbox. Analysis is riddled with these sorts of tricks, and the first time you see them you shouldn't feel bad for not understanding them immediately! Eventually "tricks" become common methods and you will look back at this moment and wonder how on earth you COULDN'T see such an "obvious" thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Delta(fg)}{h}
$$

If we're trying to relate this to the derivatives of $f$ and $g$, we'll need to find some way to relate the terms in the numerator to the expressions $\Delta f=f(x+h)-f(x)$ and $\Delta g = g(x+h)-g(x)$.

How could $f(x+h)g(x+h)$ occur as part of some expression that included $\Delta f$ and/or $\Delta g$? Well, it's the first term in $f(x+h)\Delta g$:
$$
f(x+h)\Delta g=f(x+h)[g(x+h)-g(x)]=f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x+h)g(x)
$$

So, if the numerator included a $-f(x+h)g(x)$ term, we could combine it with $f(x+h)g(x+h)$ to get something involving $\Delta g$. This suggests that it's worth trying to add and subtract $f(x+h)g(x)$: certainly subtracting it will let us do something useful to $f(x+h)g(x+h)$, and maybe we'll luck out and adding it will let us do something useful to $f(x)g(x)$. (And, as it happens, it does!)

Comment: So, when dealing with the change in the value of fg, we're also interested in how f and g change. One of the logical steps in proving the product rule, then, is to incorporate delta f and delta g into the definition of the derivative of fg. Wish I would have figured that out earlier!

Answer (score 0):

In contemplating

$$(1)\ \ \ \ f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)$$

you might curse a bit and pose yourself the question "wouldn't life be simpler if it was

$$f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x)$$

instead?" A hallowed principle of mathematical skullduggery is to just blatantly insert what you want to see, and then fess up and correct for it. So we write $(1)$ as

$$[f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x)] + [f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x+h)g(x)].$$

In other words [what we want to see] + [correction]. There is no way to know ahead of time if this nefarious scheme is going to work; the correction may be just as difficult to think about as the original. But sometimes it works just fine thank you, and this is one of those times.

Answer (score 0):

For $h\ne0$ one has, identically in $x$ and $h$, 
$$\eqalign{{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)\over h}&={f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\ g(x)+f(x)\ {g(x+h)-g(x)\over h}\cr&\qquad+\ {f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}\ {g(x+h)-g(x)\over h}\ h\ .\cr}$$
Now let $h\to0$.